# R - divide/add to all columns in data frame values from vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a vector `x,y`  and data frame `df` such that

```
NCOL(x) = NCOL(y) = ncol(df).
```

I would like to divide each columns (all rows) by vector `x` (it means: all values in column one of `df` by the fist values in vector `x`, second column (all values) by second column (one value) of vector `x`.

The same situation for adding vector `y` to columns (the same way).

Could you help me do it in elegant way ?

Comment: I posted a solution below.  Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replicate 'x' and then divide the 'df'

```
df/x[col(df)]
```

If we need to add 'y'

```
(df/x[col(df)]) + y[col(df)]
```

#### data

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:25, 5, 5))
x <- 1:5
y <- 6:10
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to transpose, perform the operations taking advantage of automatic recycling of the short vector operands, and then transpose again to return to the original transposition. This solution results in a matrix rather than a data.frame, which may not be desirable, although it can be argued that since you're performing a numerical computation on every cell of the input, it's more appropriate to store it as a numeric matrix.

Stealing akrun's data for an example:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:25,5L,5L));
x <- 1:5;
y <- 6:10;
t(t(df)/x + y);
##      V1   V2       V3    V4   V5
## [1,]  7 10.0 11.66667 13.00 14.2
## [2,]  8 10.5 12.00000 13.25 14.4
## [3,]  9 11.0 12.33333 13.50 14.6
## [4,] 10 11.5 12.66667 13.75 14.8
## [5,] 11 12.0 13.00000 14.00 15.0
```

This solution seems to have a performance benefit:

```
library(microbenchmark);
akrun <- function() df/x[col(df)] + y[col(df)];
bgoldst <- function() t(t(df)/x + y);
identical(as.data.frame(bgoldst()),akrun());
## [1] TRUE
identical(bgoldst(),as.matrix(akrun()));
## [1] TRUE
identical(bgoldst(),akrun());
## [1] FALSE
microbenchmark(akrun(),bgoldst(),times=1000L);
## Unit: microseconds
##       expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval
##    akrun() 812.542 867.9235 930.60749 894.6515 922.235 2395.288  1000
##  bgoldst()  50.036  58.5890  68.82336  67.1420  71.846 1417.672  1000
```

I've given akrun +1 for my thievery.

Comment: Plus 1 for you too.  Is the `microbenchmark` based on the small dataset?  If that is the case, it may not be that useful as a comparison method.

Comment: Good point, it was on the small dataset. I just ran some tests on much larger datasets (25,000 and 250,000 cells, trying both many-row and many-column arrangements) and got similar results.

Comment: So, it must be related to the matrix division (though you are doing a double transpose)